# Bash to find lines with exact one word?

Tags: regex, bash, sed

I'm trying to write a bash script that takes a file name, and return lines that have one word. Here is sample text:

```
This has more than one word
There
is exactly one word in above line.
         White-space
in the start of the above line doesn't matter.
Need-some-help.
```

Output:

```
There
         White-space
Need-some-help.
```

I'm looking into using a combination SED and Regex.

Note: I cannot using anything else (it has to be a bash script, without custom modules), so suggesting that wouldn't help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If words can contain any non-whitespace characters, then:

```
grep -E '^\s*\S+\s*$'
```

or

```
sed -E '/^\s*\S+\s*$/!d'
```

or

```
sed -n -E '/^\s*\S+\s*$/p'
```

Answer (score 4):

If you have awk available: `awk 'NF==1'`

sed: delete any line with a "non-space space non-space" sequence `sed '/[^ ] +[^ ]/d'`

Comment: Easiest solution. Brilliant.

Answer (score 1):

Well You could just delete lines which contain a char + space + char using sed.

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "This has more than one word
There
is exactly one word in above line.
         White-space
in the start of the above line doesn't matter.
Need-some-help." | sed '/\S \S/d' -
```

Answer (score 0):

```
^\s*\b[a-zA-Z.-]+\s*$
```

For the regex part and assuming you are searching the file line by line this regex will only match if there is exactly one word in the line.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you can use `grep` (one of the most common tools used in shell scripts):

```
#!/bin/bash
grep '^ *[^ ]\+ *$' "$@"
```